# Gaps between images

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a navbar for a friend's blog (http://testcheww.blogspot.com/), but I always get this little space:

[image]

I tried to change the quests, support and play position but it doesn't work. Any suggestions about how to fix it? Here's the code:

```
<center>
  <div style='background-image: url(http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/left.png) ; background-size: 45px 86px; height: 86px; width: 45px; border: 0px; margin-left: -1139px; margin-bottom: -80x;'/>
    </center>
    <center>
<div class='homebutton' style='position:relative; left:-477px; top:-86px;'>
    <a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/home.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/homehover.png' width='141px'/> 
    </a>
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 63px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: -750px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/home-about.png' width='63px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
    <center>
<div class='aboutbutton' style='position:relative; left:-273px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
    <a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/about.html'>
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/about.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/abouthover.png' width='141px'/> 
    </a>
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 72px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: -333px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/about-guides.png' width='72px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div class='guidesbutton' style='position:relative; left:-60px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/guides.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guides.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guideshover.png' width='141px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
        <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 58px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 78px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guides-quests.png' width='58px'/>
      </div>

<div class='questsbutton' style='position:relative; left:137px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/quests.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/quests.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/questshover.png' width='141px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
            <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 470px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/quests-support.png' width='52px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
<div class='supportbutton' style='position:relative; left:334px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/support-us.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support.png' width='150px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/supporthover.png' width='150px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 874px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support-play.png' width='54px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 142px; border: 0px; margin-top: -86px; margin-right: -1021px;'><a href='http://www.tinkatolli.com/play/'><img height='86' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/play.png' width='142'/></a>
      </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: That is very, very bad code good sir. Even though it does look very good, the code itself is very bad. `<center>` should not be used. Classes such as `a` are semantically useless. Too much inline css. No clear structure at all. Etc.

Comment: Nice little game though, very Glitch inspired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is whitespace between your images.

```
<img (content) /> 
<img (content) />
```

The return between the two images here has exactly the same function as a space. So the solution is to delete the return.

```
<img (content) /><img (content) />
```

That's it.

By the way, you shouldn't use `width` and `height` attributes (which have been deprecated since at least the beginning of this century), but if you are using them anyway, give them a number for their values, not a css-style length.
That is, `141`, not `141px`.
But actually using CSS is much better. Ditto for `<center>` elements.

And unless you're using XHTML, there is no need whatsoever to end tags with `/>`. Just `>` will do fine.

Comment: Thanks! Works now. I have another question, how could I put the whole navbar BEHIND the sidebar e.g: put the blue line under the guides title http://i.imgur.com/vicR2fn.png

Comment: That should be a new question. Don't ask two questions in one question.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the width of Quests to 143 and the width of Support to 152, an increase of 2 pixels each (a and b), and it looks fine.

[image]

Probably not the best way to fix it, but I don't really understand your layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<center>
  <div style='background-image: url(http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/left.png) ; background-size: 45px 86px; height: 86px; width: 45px; border: 0px; margin-left: -1139px; margin-bottom: -80x;'/>
    </center>
    <center>
<div class='homebutton' style='position:relative; left:-477px; top:-86px;'>
    <a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/home.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/homehover.png' width='141px'/> 
    </a>
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 63px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: -750px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/home-about.png' width='63px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
    <center>
<div class='aboutbutton' style='position:relative; left:-273px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
    <a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/about.html'>
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/about.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/abouthover.png' width='141px'/> 
    </a>
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 72px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: -333px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/about-guides.png' width='72px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div class='guidesbutton' style='position:relative; left:-60px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/guides.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guides.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guideshover.png' width='141px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
        <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 58px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 78px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/guides-quests.png' width='58px'/>
      </div>

<div class='questsbutton' style='position:relative; left:137px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/quests.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/quests.png' width='141px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/questshover.png' width='141px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
            <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 458px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/quests-support.png' width='52px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
<div class='supportbutton' style='position:relative; left:334px; top:-86px; margin-bottom: -82px;'>
<a href='http://www.tinkatollidunes.com/p/support-us.html'> 
<img alt='' class='a' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support.png' width='150px'/> 
<img alt='' class='b' height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/supporthover.png' width='150px'/> 
</a> 
</div>
    </center>
    <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 52px; border: 0px; margin-top: -172px; margin-left: 870px;'><img height='86px' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/support-play.png' width='54px'/>
      </div>
    </center>
        <center>
      <div style='height: 86px; width: 142px; border: 0px; margin-top: -86px; margin-right: -1021px;'><a href='http://www.tinkatolli.com/play/'><img height='86' src='http://files.tinkatollidunes.com/nav/play.png' width='142'/></a>
      </div>
    </center>
```